# what is different with Transitions external internal and local ? in Spring doc 11.5 Configuring Transitions

Tags: spring-statemachine

11.5 Configuring Transitions
We support three different types of transitions, external, internal and local. Transitions are either triggered by a signal which is an event sent into a state machine or a timer.
I donot konw what is different .

Answer (score 14, accepted):

#### Internal

You can think of internal transition as self-transition - from A to A;
Source and target state are always the same.

#### Local and External

Most of the time these two are equivalent, with the exception of when transitioning between super and sub-states. Local transition doesn’t cause exit and entry to source state if target state is a substate of a source state or if  the target is a superstate of a source state.

Please consult the [official UML specification](https://www.omg.org/spec/UML/2.5/PDF) (section 14.5.11 - Transition class, especially - Constraints section, where the above is formally defined) upon which the Spring state machine is implemented.

Comment: thanks to mention that spring state machine is based on UML specs

Answer (score 0):

It is really interesting, that the Spring State Machine is modelled upon UML spec. But there is also documentation about the nature of the transitions within the official docs here at https://docs.spring.io/spring-statemachine/docs/current/reference/#transitions

> Transitions
> A transition is a relationship between a source state and a target state. A switch from one state to another is a state transition caused by a trigger.

> Internal Transition
> Internal transition is used when an action needs to be run without causing a state transition. In an internal transition, the source state and the target state is always the same, and it is identical with a self-transition in the absence of state entry and exit actions.

> External versus Local Transitions
> In most cases, external and local transitions are functionally equivalent, except in cases where the transition happens between super and sub states. Local transitions do not cause exit and entry to a source state if the target state is a substate of a source state. Conversely, local transitions do not cause exit and entry to a target state if the target is a superstate of a source state. The following image shows the difference between local and external transitions with very simplistic super and sub states: {here a really good visual explanation follows, which I can not paste, so please follow the link}